# Primary key unique constraint is disabled after import into Azure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Many months ago we were running our website (ASP.NET C#) locally on premise and decided to migrate our website and database into azure (WebApp and Azure SQL). Everything was migrated successfully and we encountered minimal issues.
Now we just spotted that it seems that during our import of our SQL database into Azure SQL it disabled all constraints including PK constraints and unique constraints, etc.
I was wondering if anyone has encountered this before and what can be done to fix the issue?

The idea that I'm working with right now, and not sure if it would work, is to export the database from Azure SQL using **SqlPackage.exe** and **VerifyExtraction=false** and hopefully, that would work because otherwise the export doesn’t work because it’s trying to verify the schema, then import it to my local SQL server, try to run `EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"` (I believe `sp_msforeachtable` is not available in Azure SQL). And if that works and the constraints are re-enabled properly, then try importing it back into Azure SQL again, assuming it won’t try to disable them again.

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

[image: Example of the disabled primary key constraint]

Comment: Why make this so difficult? Trivial searching will find scripts that search through the metadata. Here is one that [finds all disabled constraints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103528/find-constraint-disabled-in-sql-server). If you can find them, you can write a script to enable them - pay attention to the proper order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

"Everything was migrated successfully and we encountered minimal issues."

I doubt that's actually true. It sounds like the import has failed to add primary keys and constraints during database restore, which is actually a pretty big deal.

If your database is small (think less than 10 million rows total across all tables) you could code a script to add primary keys and clustered indexes in-situ by using the ALTER TABLE statement.

If your database is any bigger than that, you'll need to either re-import it from scratch, paying attention to any error logs this time, or build new tables, select all your data into them, drop the existing tables and rename your new tables to what the old tables were named.

I guess it all depends on how many tables you have and how many rows they have as to which approach will be best for you.

SSMS has some great tools and shortcuts to do this sort of stuff. Right click table, click "Script as", click "create to", click "new query window" and voila, you have a create table statement ready to go. Add your constraints to it, rename it to [Tablename]2, run it, and voila! You've just created a new table with a Primary Key constraint. Select everything out of the existing table into your new table, delete the old table, rename your new table back to what the old table was named and bam, you're done.

If you need to do this 20 times, no big deal. If you need to do this 2000 times, you can script these operations into one long query.